# How to Display the MultiIndex object of a data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe

I had a DataFrame `jobs_2` which has many columns, amongst which are `city` and `state`.

From `jobs_2` I created a new DataFrame `jobs_2i` where state and city are set as indices of `jobs_2`.

For that I used the code:

```
jobs_2i = jobs_2.set_index(['state', 'city'])
```

I now need to use an appropriate property of data frames to display the MultiIndex object of `jobs_2i`, but I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: By display, do you mean to print elements or parse through dataframe for some operation?